# Check if previous status is returned so the user can borrow books again

Tags: php, laravel

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cqbj.jpg)

How to compare/check if the previous status of a user is returned. If it is returned then that user can borrow a book. If not or if the previous status is currently borrowed then he can't borrow a book.

The code seems incorrect. If the user borrows a book the fix status will always be 'pending.'

Heres what I did but it won't work.

```
if ($borrow->status === 'Returned') {
    $borrow = new BorrowBook();
    $borrow->book_name = $borrow->book_name;
    $borrow->date_borrowed = $borrow->date_borrowed('date_borrowed');
    $borrow->status = 'Pending';
} elseif (BorrowBook::where('status', $borrow->status === 'Currently Borrowed')->exist()) {
    return redirect('/borrow')->with('success', 'Your previous book has not been returned yet');
}
```

Comment: What was the error returned

Comment: There should be a space in your else if, you should save the transaction if it is returned, $borrow->save() should be the last line in the if statement if returned.

Comment: the error is that it will always got to the elseif statement "Your previous book has not been returned yet" even though the status of the previous data is RETURNED

Comment: Can you post the full function code

Comment: the one I posted at the top

Comment: Is your status for returned in all caps like "RETURNED" or capitalized "Returned", cos you wrote that the status of the previous data is RETURNED

Comment: its Returned.... somehow it wont check the previous data that the user has it will just go directly to the else statement

Comment: Can i see where the $borrow data is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Some how your `elseif` is always return true, Try to use this,

```
elseif(count(BorrowBook::where('status',$borrow->status == "Currently Borrowed")->get())) {
    return redirect('/borrow')->with('success','Your previous book has not been returned yet');
}
```

Comment: so the first IF statement is correct? it will just see if the status is returned or not?

Comment: Yes ! it just check.

Comment: @Carolinian Advice but you don't store status as boolean, why are you checking if your status is boolean in your else if condition